# Delete the empty list from a main list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete the empty list from a main list.
Input is:

```
my_list = [[''],[''],s-13,s-12]
```

Output:

```
my_modified_list = [,,s-13,s-12]
```

I tried with this but when I put the list in df in pandas, its not working

```
my_modified_list = data[sublist for sublist in my_list of any(sublist)]
```

Finally this is my probable solution

```
i = 0
while i<Len(my_list):
    if my_list[i]==['']:
        my_list[i]=''
    i+=i
```

Comment: What you mean by two commas in your `my_modified_list` ?

Comment: If any empty list is there it will be replaced by None

Answer (score 0):

May be:

```
    my_list = [[''], [''], 's - 13', 's - 12']
    new_list = [a for a in my_list if a[0]]
    print(new_list)
```